# Projectile Physics?

Tags: roblox

What is the ideal way to implement projectile physics, like a cannonball or arrow? I've been experimenting with BodyForce / BodyVelocity but those look like they're applying a constant, non-diminishing force / velocity to the projectile which doesn't look realistic. I've also just set the Velocity property of the projectile directly which works better, but I'm assuming there's a standard pattern used  for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

In physics, velocity is split into 2 components, the vertical component and the horizontal component. When a projectile is in motion through the air, we don't consider air resistence affecting its speed, as it's such a minute force.

Since velocity is split into 2 components, if velocity changes or is applied horizontally, that horizonal velocity or force does not affect the vertical force or velocity, and vice versa. This is why projectiles travel at a constant speed horizontally. The vertical velocity, however, is not constant. Due to gravity, the projectile will fall to the earth faster over time. This is acceleration.

What you could try is to add a body velocity with a high value, such as 400,400,0: a velocity for the x, y and z axis, and then immediately remove the velocity a fraction of a second later. What this does is creates an initial velocity, which eventually gets changed by gravity on the y component.

To learn more about projectile physics, you can check out online resources such as the following:

```
http://bowlesphysics.com/images/AP_Physics_B_-_Projectile_Motion.pdf
```